# how to do a login in ionic with http post?

Tags: ionic-framework, authentication, xmlhttprequest

i'm developing an app that require a login, so i've a controller that post on the server mail and password inserted in the form and if the login is succesfully i print in $scope.response the string `"T"` and the in the controller i should verify if the string is `"T"` and then redirect the user to the homepage.

this is my code:

**FORM HTML**:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
                <div class="list">
                  <label class="item item-input">
                    <span class="input-label">Email</span>
                    <input type="email" name="mail" ng-model="data.mail">
                  </label><br>
                  <label class="item item-input">
                    <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" ng-model="data.pwd">
                  </label><br>
                  <input type="hidden" name="funzione" value="login" ng-model="data.funzione">
                  <input class="button button-calm" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
                </div>
            </form>
```

**CONTROLLER**:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http, $state) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.submit = function(){
        var link = 'http://localhost/ShuttleFIX/api.php';
        $http.post(link, {mail : $scope.data.mail}, {pwd : $scope.data.pwd}, {funzione : $scope.data.funzione})
            .then(function (res){
                $scope.response = res.data;
                if ($scope.response == "T"){
                    state.go('main');
                }
            });
    };
});
```

**API**:

```
/*
 * connection to DB
 */
 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }
    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
        exit(0);
    }
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
 if (isset($postdata)) {
 $request = json_decode($postdata);
 $funzione = $request->funzione;
 if ($funzione == "login") {
    $mail = $request->mail;
    $pwd = $request->pwd;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM utente WHERE mail = '$mail' AND pwd = '$pwd'";
    $res = mysql_query($query);                                                         
    if ($res && mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) { 
        $response = "T";
        echo $response;
    }
 }
```

but it doesn't work.

How can i solve this problem?

Thank's

**UPDATE**:

I received this error from the console: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/<path>/api.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 0):

A common server-side issue.Add these headers on the server side.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Note: take a look here for further help, https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled

Also a step by step guide can be found here: http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/codeproject/posting-data-from-ionic-app-to-php-server/

Comment: I edited my answer with a link. Hope this help. Also this problem appears in browser. You can use chrome extension for cors https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi to solve this issue.